How/why does Mocha suppress unhandled promise rejections, and how can I prevent it from doing this?
Node.js's default behaviour when a promise rejection is unhandled is to terminate the process.
node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "argh".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}

Node.js v18.17.1

During Mocha testing however, this doesn't seem to happen. This is a problem for me because I am trying to create a regression test for a bug which caused an unhandled promise rejection to terminate Node.js. I am unable to create a Mocha test which reproduces this behaviour.
it('test', () => {
  Promise.reject('argh')
})

  √ test

  1 passing (3ms)

I have inspected Mocha's code trying to figure out how Mocha suppresses Node.js's default behaviour in this case but I can't figure it out. I know that you can set process.addEventListener('unhandledRejection', ...) and Mocha does indeed do this, but during that handler it removes its own handler and re-emits the event, which should trigger Node.js's default behaviour - but still nothing happens. I also can't find any Mocha documentation about this.

How does Mocha suppress unhandled promise rejections? Also, why? Is this this a bug?
Is there any way that I can configure Mocha to stop doing this?


The result will change based on your version of mocha, (there's a closed issue thread discussing it here) but the short version is that Mocha will simply just swallow unhandled rejections (not quite - they emit an unhandledRejection event to the node process, and do emit a log message in debug mode).
As for the reasoning behind it, it seems to involve a change in node's behavior between node versions. See the commit message that introduced this change.
There are two simple ways you can fix this:

Run node with unhandled-rejections in strict mode. You can set node environment options in your preferred flavor format of mocha settings. For example - .mocharc.json:

{
  "node-option": ["unhandled-rejections=strict"]
}

This will cause mocha to fail the test with something similar to:
Uncaught UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "foobar".


Listen for the unhandledRejection event in the node process and (presumably) re-throw the error yourself, by adding this to your tests:

process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason) => {
  throw reason;
});

